# User-defined-function for join

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

How to create an `UDF` for `outer join`
Say for example, I have below column with type as follows

```
ColA: String
ColB: Seq[Row]
```

DF1:

```
ColA ColB
1    [(1,2),(1,3)]
2    [(2,3),(3,4)]
```

DF2:

```
ColA ColB
1    [(1,2),(1,4)]
3    [(2,5),(3,4)]
```

Results:

```
 ColA    newCol
    1    [(1,2),(1,3)]
    2    [(2,3),(3,4)]
    3    [(2,5),(3,4)]
```

Code example:

```
val joinDf=DF1.join(DF2,DF1(ColA)===DF2(ColA),"outer")
    .withColumn("newCol", when(DF1(ColB).isNull,DF2(ColB))
        .otherwise(when(DF2(ColB).isNull,DF1(ColB)).otherwise(DF1(ColB))))
    .select(col("colA"),col("newCol"))

val joinUdf=udf((a: Seq[Row],b: Seq[Row]) => (a,b) match {
    case (null,b) => a
    case (a,null) => b
    case (a,b) => b
}
```

This throws an error.

> > Java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:: Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.Row is not supported

Comment: what is the error you are getting ? please update that too

Comment: can you update your DF1 schema too?

Comment: seq[Row] is not possible in dataframes. it is possible in RDD.

Comment: You don't need to define udf function. Just rename column name of DF2 and join them appropriately as i have mentioned in my answer below. :) you should be fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Given that the `schema` of first dataframe `DF1` is

```
root
 |-- ColA: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- ColB: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _1: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- _2: integer (nullable = false)
```

You have to rename your `DF2` as

```
+----+--------------+
|ColA|ColC          |
+----+--------------+
|1   |[[1,2], [1,3]]|
|3   |[[2,5], [3,4]]|
+----+--------------+
```

and with `schema`

```
root
 |-- ColA: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- ColC: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _1: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- _2: integer (nullable = false)
```

and use the following code where you don't even need a `udf` function as inbuilt `when` function is used

```
val joinDf=DF1.join(DF2, Seq("ColA"),"outer")
  .withColumn("newCol", when(DF1("ColB").isNull, col("ColC"))
  .otherwise(col("ColB")))
  .select(col("colA"),col("newCol"))
```

You should get your desired output as

```
+----+--------------+
|colA|newCol        |
+----+--------------+
|1   |[[1,2], [1,3]]|
|3   |[[2,5], [3,4]]|
|2   |[[2,3], [3,4]]|
+----+--------------+

root
 |-- colA: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- newCol: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _1: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- _2: integer (nullable = false)
```

Comment: isn't this answer helpful ? :) if it helped you, please accept and upvote